# stopPropagation prevents bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery to hide and show sidebar, if I click outside or resize the sidebar hide, but I fall in a problem so all my dropdown are stopped because I use stopPropagation

My HTML is

```js
$('#btn-menusb-l').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#sdbr-l').toggleClass("ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob");
 });
 $('#sdbr-l').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
 $('body,html').click(function(e){
  $('#sdbr-l').removeClass('ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob');
 });
 $(window).resize(function(){
  $('#sdbr-l').removeClass('ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob');
 });
```

```css
.ly-bmk-header
{
   border:0;
   border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
   margin:0 auto;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   min-width: 360px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: auto !important;
   padding: 0 10px
}

.hdr-table
{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.hdr-cell
{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}




.ly-bmk-layout
{
   display: table-row;
}

.ly-bmk-cell
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
}


.ly-bmk-sidebar-l, .ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob
{
   background: #FFFFFF;
   border-right:1px solid #A6A6A6;
   margin:0;
   width: 330px;
}

.ly-bmk-content
{
   margin:0 auto;
}

@media all and (max-width: 750px)
{
    .ly-bmk-sidebar-l
 {position:fixed;margin-left:-340px}
 .ly-bmk-sidebar-l.ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob
 {margin-left:0px;position:fixed;z-index:11111;overflow-y:auto;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
 height: 100%;
  top: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="ly-bmk-sheet">
   <header class="ly-bmk-header">
    <div class="hdr-table">
     <div class="hdr-cell">
      <nav class="ly-bmk-navc">
       <ul class="ly-bmk-hmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
     <div class="hdr-cell">
      <nav class="ly-bmk-navc">
       <ul class="ly-bmk-hmenu">
        <li><a id="btn-menusb-l" href="#">Sidebar</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
     <div class="hdr-cell">
      <nav class="ly-bmk-navc">
       <ul class="ly-bmk-hmenu">
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown">DropDwon Header</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <div class="ly-bmk-layout">
    <div id="sdbr-l" class="ly-bmk-cell ly-bmk-sidebar-l">
     
      <div class="ly-bmk-vmenu-content">
       <ul class="ly-bmk-vmenu">
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown">DropDwon SideBar</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ly-bmk-cell ly-bmk-content">
      <p>WELCOME</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I want to keep sidebar shown if I click inside but hide if I click outside, my jquery code working except it stop my dropdown from showing

- Sidebar hide if width is less than 750px
- sidebar in header to show the sidebar if width is less than 750px
- dropdown inside sidebar not working but the one in header working

Comment: You didn't provide a working bootstrap example and therefore cannot ascertain if this is programmer error

Comment: it's bootstrap dropdown

Comment: No, I added that code to a snippet with bootstrap and it did not render at all.  It's incomplete.  Though, an answer could be provided with the code given, I encourage you to provide a working example to make it easier for those answering the question

Comment: I add all my code HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT, dropdown in header work but in sidebar not work if you click on sidebar on header will show sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: I didn't look into this too closely.  A better answer may exist and in that case, I may delete this.  Since there isn't another answer yet, I'm offering this on the basis that a partial/incomplete answer may be better than no answer and leave it to the community to update/edit this.**

---

### Discriminate Elements

In your click events, you need to determine when the propagation should stop.  Below this is done by sniffing the target element as well as evaluating its ancestry.

I get the class of the parent element and the class of the closest `UL` if it exists and check to see if the class is a `dropdown` (button) or `dropdown-menu` (menu list).  If it is, then the event may continue, otherwise the propagation is halted:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#btn-menusb-l').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#sdbr-l').toggleClass("ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob");
  });
  
  $('#sdbr-l').click(function(e) {
    let classes = Array.from(e.target.classList)
    if (e.target.closest('ul') != null)
      classes=classes.concat(Array.from(e.target.closest('ul').classList))
    if (e.target.parentElement != null)
      classes=classes.concat(Array.from(e.target.parentElement.classList))

    if (!(classes.includes('dropdown') || classes.includes('dropdown-menu')))
      e.stopPropagation()
  });
  
  $('body,html').click(function(e) {
    let classes = Array.from(e.target.classList)
    if (e.target.closest('ul') != null)
      classes=classes.concat(Array.from(e.target.closest('ul').classList))
    if (e.target.parentElement != null)
      classes=classes.concat(Array.from(e.target.parentElement.classList))
    
    if (!(classes.includes('dropdown') || classes.includes('dropdown-menu')))
      $('#sdbr-l').removeClass('ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob');     
  });
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#sdbr-l').removeClass('ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob');
  });

})
```

```css
.ly-bmk-header {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: auto !important;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.hdr-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.hdr-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ly-bmk-layout {
  display: table-row;
}

.ly-bmk-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.ly-bmk-sidebar-l,
.ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
  margin: 0;
  width: 330px;
}

.ly-bmk-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
  .ly-bmk-sidebar-l {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -340px
  }
  .ly-bmk-sidebar-l.ly-bmk-sidebar-l-mob {
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 11111;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="ly-bmk-sheet">
    <header class="ly-bmk-header">
      <div class="hdr-table">
        <div class="hdr-cell">
          <nav class="ly-bmk-navc">
            <ul class="ly-bmk-hmenu">
              <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="hdr-cell">
          <nav class="ly-bmk-navc">
            <ul class="ly-bmk-hmenu">
              <li><a id="btn-menusb-l" href="#">Sidebar</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="hdr-cell">
          <nav class="ly-bmk-navc">
            <ul class="ly-bmk-hmenu">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown Header</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="ly-bmk-layout">
      <div id="sdbr-l" class="ly-bmk-cell ly-bmk-sidebar-l">

        <div class="ly-bmk-vmenu-content">
          <ul class="ly-bmk-vmenu">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown SideBar</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ly-bmk-cell ly-bmk-content">
      <p>WELCOME</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```